# Did Aisha Poison Muhammad?

Tags: islam

There are at least 2 sources that claim this

According to [Quora: Why do some Shias claim that Prophet Muhammad was poisoned by Aisha and Hafsa?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-Shias-claim-that-Prophet-Muhammad-was-poisoned-by-Aisha-and-Hafsa):

> 2- According to a special narration, narrated in some books (among
>   them Sahih Bokhari, v.4, p.1618/ Sahih Muslim, v.4, p.1733/
>   Al-Maghazi, v.5, p.2159/ etc.), Ayesha was quoted saying: “I forcibly
>   put some medicine in prophet Muhammad’s mouth. Then he pointed out to
>   me with his hand showing that I shouldn’t do this. We thought that
>   this is because an ill person wouldn’t like any drug…”

[Quora: Who killed prophet Muhammad?](https://www.quora.com/Who-killed-prophet-Muhammad) (also [here](https://www.quora.com/What-were-the-probable-reasons-to-kill-Prophet-Mohammad-by-poisoning)) says:

> Imam al-Sadiq (as) was sitting with a group of his followers, and
>   asked them: "Do you know whether the Prophet died a natural death or
>   was murdered?
>
> Allah the Almighty says: "if then he died or is killed".
>
> The truth is that the Prophet was poisoned in his last days before he
>   died. Ayesha and Hafsa administered poison in his food. Upon hearing
>   this, the Imam Sadiq's followers said that they and their fathers were
>   among the worst villains ever created by Allah."

The second source is suspicious. Who is Imam Sadiq? Muslims don't believe anyone can talk to Allah. Is the haditz reliable?

[Searching Google for Aisha Poison Muhammad](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=aisha+poison+muhammad&rlz=1C1JPGB_enID637ID637&ei=C0O8W7LKHoOCvQSO6oSgAg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1920&bih=1007) shows many results too.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq

Comment: You never included a link to your second quotation.

Comment: I think there's a notable source making a claim in there somewhere (or perhaps more than one), but "random Quora doc online" isn't it.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Islam SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are plenty of such claims. Islam SE may be very bias. So I asked here too

Comment: "Did she..." -- according to whom? You seem to be asking for objective criteria; I don't think there will be any. So we're looking at unproven claims.

Comment: We are looking at notable claim and I am asking whether the claim is true false credible or not credible. Is this on topic? If we want to be technical, nothing can be proven beyond any doubt. How credible it is?

Comment: Islam.SE would be suitable for religious (scripture-based) perspectives on the matter: "Is X a Shia belief?" rather than "Is X true?"  This question would likely be closed at Islam.SE (as it stands) as it's a "defend your beliefs" question (at least the version in the title is: *Did Aisha Poison Muhammad?*).

Comment: @SharenEayrs: I do not challenge its credibility or notability. But how do you imagine "proof" on a 1500-year-old "cold case" would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept that Aisha poisoned Muhammed is old and extremely suspect, especially coming from Shia of that era, as Shia already believe that Aisha betrayed the Prophet's family. Muhammed was really weird with folk cures and poisonings to begin with (the leading contender for his cause of death being a [poisoned sheep](http://www.answeringmuslims.com/2011/10/who-killed-muhammad.html) given to him after he conquered Khaybar because the person (their identity varies from story to story) thought that if Muhammed was a conquerer, then they'd be rid of him, but if he was a prophet, he'd know it was poisoned). [He lingered for quite a while after this incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeynab_bint_Al-Harith#The_Poisoned_Lamb), choosing to spend most of his time with Aisha. So Aisha was with him when he died. Did she kill him? It was 1500 years ago.

Likewise, your second source referencing [Imam Sadiq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) (the Sixth Imam) comes from the [Tafsir Ayyashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir_Ayyashi), a book written by al-Ayyashi in 932 CE that is an exegesis of Imam proclamations from ages past. Ayyashi was very similar to modern-day Pinterest users in that he was more interested in gathering information than whether or not that information was: 1. Original or 2. Correct. He was especially interested in gathering texts that supported his already-existing opinions. So while there is a slim possibility that Imam Sadiq said that thing 180 years before Ayyashi wrote it down, it's more likely that it was [a bit of a game of telephone over 180 years](http://www.askthesheikh.com/did-the-wives-of-the-prophet-poison-him-as-narrated-by-al-ayyashi/), and Ayyashi wrote down the version he liked the best.

Bottom line, considering there's a lot of bad emotions tied up with this era (bad enough to sever Sunni from Shia!) it's impossible to know which story is right. From a scholar's perspective, none of these works were written within Aisha's lifetime, and the writers had axes to grind.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to cite your sources, and even then I'm not sure this is up to standard even with sources cited.

Comment: He cited his sources and it's good enough. Conclusive? No. But it's as good as it gets.